# How to make interface in javascript and call android method?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, interface

I am building an android application where There is loading a defeat HTTP file on webView which is place on assets folder. Below is code of defeat HTTP file.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="init();">Click on this link for a log 
message</a>
<br><br><br><br><br>

 <script>
function init(){
    android.log('Data from JS');
    android.log(android.data);
}

function showMessage(str){
    android.log(str);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

OnCreate Code

```
 //add interface
    wv.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "android");//android is the 
    keyword that will be exposed in js
```

OnClick method and interface method

```
 public void click(View view){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        wv.evaluateJavascript("javascript:showMessage('Hello World!')", null);
    }
}

//javascript interface
private class JsInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    //function that will be called from assets/test.js
    //js example: android.log('my message');
    public String data() {
        return "DATA FROM ANDROID";
    }

    public void log(String msg) {
        Log.d("MSG FROM JAVASCRIPT", msg);
    }
}
```

Above is complete code how I am using interface in JavaScript. A long back I Had used the same it was working in my old project but now it's not working can any once answer me is this method is deprecated in android or there any other work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is js interface class     :

```
public class JS_INTERFACE {

    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JS_INTERFACE(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void native_showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void native_ShowNotifyTest1(String toast , String BigOrSmall ) {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}


 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    WebSettings settings = webView1.getSettings();

    // Enable Javascript
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView1.addJavascriptInterface(new JS_INTERFACE(getContext()), "android");

}
```

I use onCreateView for init .

**Updated answer :**

Use JQ in your app (simple use evaluateJavascript):

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        webView.evaluateJavascript("someJQFunction();", null);

    } 
else {

        webView.loadUrl("javascript: someJQFunction();");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks can you tell me how to add jQuery in android

Answer (score -1):

Add `@JavascriptInterface` before `public void log(String msg)`.